# ¿Problemas al carga pagina inicio con IIS 10?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, iis

Tengo una aplicación web hecho MVC VB.net en un servidor  2022 con IIS 10, que al loquearme cargan la pagina de inicio sin problemas desde mi PC (windows), sin embargo cuando accedo desde un móvil Android/IOS. después de loguearse muestra el siguiente error.
"Error al procesar la solicitud."

lo mas curioso es si lo publico en otro servidor con IIS versión 10. entro sin problemas, es decir la pagina de inicio si que lo carga bien.

Comparto el siguiente extracto de código para redireccionar cuando el acceso es correcto.

Login:

```
       ' GET: Equipos

   <HttpPost()>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Function Index(oLogin As Login) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then

                Dim response As CaptchaResponse = ValidateCaptcha(Request.Params("token"))

                If response.Success = False Then
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "CAPTCHA INVÁLIDO. RECARGUE LA PAGINA")
                    Return View(oLogin)
                End If



                Dim return_url = ""
                If Request("Return_Url") IsNot Nothing AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request("Return_Url")) = False Then
                    
                    return_url = Request("Return_url")
                End If

                Dim hashPassword = Cifrados.getSHA1Hash(oLogin.Password)
                Dim sIP As String = Utiles.GetIPAddress()

                Dim oEncontrado = tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionDL.getLoginGeo(oLogin.Usuario, hashPassword)

                If oEncontrado IsNot Nothing Then

                    'Verificar si usuario esta bloqueado
                    If oEncontrado.FechaBloqueo IsNot Nothing Then
                        oLogin = Nothing
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Acceso restringido, contactar con soporte: info@einsa.es")
                        Return View(oLogin)
                    End If

                    Dim MiIP As String = Utiles.GetIPAddress()

                    oEncontrado.IPUltimaSesion = MiIP
                    oEncontrado.FechaUltimaSesion = Now
                    oEncontrado.IntentosFallidos = 0
                    oEncontrado.FechaBloqueo = Nothing

                    'si la IP es diferente que la de EINSA, guarda
                    If MiIP <> "::1" And MiIP.StartsWith("192.168.") = False And MiIP.Trim <> "80.36.206.11" And MiIP <> "81.43.65.81" And MiIP <> "127.0.0.1" Then
                        tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionDL.guardar(oEncontrado)
                    End If

                    Dim oLoginHis As New tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionHis
                    oLoginHis.Usuario = oEncontrado.mUsuario
                    oLoginHis.IPSession = oEncontrado.IPUltimaSesion
                    oLoginHis.Fecha = Now

                    'Guardo Historico
                    tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionHISDL.guardar(oLoginHis)

                    SessionHelper.Usuario = oEncontrado.mUsuario
                    If oEncontrado.NumeroCliente IsNot Nothing Then
                        SessionHelper.NumeroCliente = oEncontrado.NumeroCliente
                    End If

                    Dim oCliente = ClientesDL.getxNumeroOT(oEncontrado.NumeroCliente)

                    If oCliente IsNot Nothing Then
                        SessionHelper.Nombre = oCliente.Nombre
                    End If

                    ''Si IP ES DIFERENTE DE LA RED LOCAL NI IP DE EINSA
                    ActividadSospechosa(sIP, oEncontrado.mUsuario, Request.UserAgent, Request.Url.ToString, "Acceso web")

                    'If sIP <> "::1" And sIP.StartsWith("192.168.") = False And sIP <> "80.36.206.11" And sIP <> "81.43.65.81" And sIP <> "127.0.0.1" Then
                    '    Dim contenido As String = String.Format("USUARIO: {0} <br/>IP: {1} <br/>NAVEGADOR: {2} <br/>URL: {3}<br/>", oEncontrado.mUsuario, sIP, Request.UserAgent, Request.Url)
                    '    contenido = contenido & "GEOIP: https://geoiptool.com/es/?ip=" & sIP
                    '    Emails.enviarEmailShared(Emails.strEmailIT, "ACTIVIDAD SOSPECHOSA EN WEBGEOLOCALIZACION", contenido, esHtml:=True, IP:=sIP)
                    'End If

                    If SessionHelper.EsPruebas Then
                        SessionHelper.Nombre = oEncontrado.mUsuario
                        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Equipos")
                    Else
                        SessionHelper.NumeroCliente = oEncontrado.NumeroCliente 'oCliente.NumeroCliente
                        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(return_url) = False Then
                            'Response.Redirect("~/" & Request("Return_Url"), False)
                            Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Equipos")
                        Else
                            Return RedirectToAction("index", "Equipos")
                            'Dim return_urlx = Request("Return_Url")

                        End If
                    End If

                Else

                    Dim oLoginx = tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionDL.getUsuario(oLogin.Usuario)

                    If oLoginx IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim intentos As Integer = 0
                        intentos = oLoginx.IntentosFallidos.GetValueOrDefault


                        If intentos >= MAXIMOS_INTENTOS_ACCESO Then
                            oLoginx.FechaBloqueo = Now
                            tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionDL.guardar(oLoginx)
                            oLogin = Nothing
                            'ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuario bloqueado, contactar con soporte: info@midominio.es")
                            'Response.Redirect("~/" & Request("Return_Url"), False)

                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "contactar con soporte: info@einsa.es")
                            Return View(oLogin)
                        Else
                            intentos += 1
                            oLoginx.IntentosFallidos = intentos
                            tbLoginWebGeolocalizacionDL.guardar(oLoginx)
                            oLogin = Nothing
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Quedan " & MAXIMOS_INTENTOS_ACCESO - intentos & " intentos")

                        End If
                    Else

                        oLogin = Nothing
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", " usuario o contraseña invalidos")

                    End If
                   
                End If
            Else
                oLogin = Nothing
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Es obligatorio introducir usuario y contraseña")
            End If

            Return View(oLogin)

        End Function

Si es correcto llama a la siguiente función para cargar la lista de equipos
```

Carga la pagina de Inicio

```
 Function Index(sNumCliente As String, sChasis As String) As ActionResult
    
                If SessionHelper.Usuario Is Nothing Then
                    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login")
                End If
    
                Dim lst As New List(Of spE_WEBEquiposGPS_ListaEquiposGPSxNUMCliente_Result)
                If SessionHelper.EsPruebas Then
                    lst = EquiposGeolocalizacionDL.ListaEquiposGPSxNUMCliente(sNumCliente, sChasis)
                Else
                    lst = EquiposGeolocalizacionDL.ListaEquiposGPSxNUMCliente(SessionHelper.NumeroCliente, sChasis)
                   
                End If
    
                    Return View(lst)
        
                End Function
```

lo que he me he dado cuenta, que despues de hacer el login en la URL muestra esta direccion en windows
https://pruebas.midominio.es/Equipos

sin embargo si lo ejecuto desde un Android muestra:
https://pruebas.midominio.es/

No se si es un problema de configuración del IIS en este nuevo servidor con Windows 2022 con IIS versión 10, si lo publico en otra servidor con Windows 2019 con IIS versión 10 acceso sin problemas después de loguearme.

Si alguien me puede brindar su ayuda, estaré muy agradecido